# Are runtime Strings interned?

Tags: java, string-interning

Here's my code:

```
public class StringExperimenter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "This is" + "limafoxtrottango";
        String s2 = "This is" + getName();
        String s3 = "This is" + getName();
        System.out.println(s1 == s2);  // prints false
        System.out.println(s3 == s2);  // prints false
    }

    private static String getName() {
        return "limafoxtrotango";
    }
}
```

Now, I understand that `s1` is evaluated by the compiler at **compile-time** and it is then **interned**.

But, what about `s2` and `s3`? Both of these are created at **runtime**. So, are two **different strings** created? Do these strings go to the constant string pool?

Comment: The answer is in the question. If they were, true would be printed instead of false.

Comment: So, both s2 and s3 go to the regular heap, correct? (I mean, both of them are managed by the JVM just like strings created using new).

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: `s1` interns the complete string `This islimafoxtrottango`, as the string concatenation happens at compile-time. The other two require a method call, only the intermediate strings are interned. The concatenation is not, as it happens at runtime. You can check the **JLS** (Java Language Specification) for details on this behavior, every valid Java implementation must do it exactly that way.

Comment: @Zabuza What do you mean by the intermediate strings are interned? Does this mean that for s2, "This is" and "limafoxtrottango" will be interned? As much as I have read, strings literals in constant expressions are not interned. But since this is not a constant expression, will the strings be interned?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying. `"This is"` is interned and `"limafoxtrotango"` is too. Following usages will use the cached version. This is because they are constant expressions. Constant expressions representing strings are always interned according to the JLS.

Comment: They indeed are, just checked the bytecode. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`s1` is completely interned, i.e.

```
This islimafoxtrottango
```

as the string concatenation happens at **compile-time**.

The other two require a **method call**, only the intermediate strings are interned. The concatenation is not, as it happens at **runtime**.

You also observed that already, as

```
System.out.println(s1 == s2);    //prints false
System.out.println(s3 == s2);    //prints false
```

would otherwise print `true`.

---

You can check the **JLS** (Java Language Specification) for details on this behavior, every valid Java implementation must do it exactly that way.

From [JLS§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) about *Constant Expressions*:

> A **constant expression** is an expression denoting a value of primitive type or a `String` that does not complete abruptly and is composed using only the following:

The following list contains more or less:

> - literals
> - operators like +
> - constant variables

Importantly, it does **not** list any method calls, even if they return a *constant* value.

It also states that:

> Constant expressions of type `String` are **always "*interned*"** so as to **share unique instances**, using the method `String.intern`.

Comment: Will "This is" and "limafoxtrottango" be interned (in case of s2 or s3)?

Answer (score 2):

If you compile your class from the command line like this:

```
javac.exe -g StringExperimenter.java
```

And then use `javap.exe -v StringExperimenter.class` to study the resulting class file, then you will see, that the following byte code is generated:

```
...  
public static void main(java.lang.String...);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC, ACC_VARARGS
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=4, args_size=1
         0: ldc           #2                  // String This islimafoxtrottango
         2: astore_1
         3: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
         6: dup
         7: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
        10: ldc           #5                  // String This is
        12: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder
        15: invokestatic  #7                  // Method getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
        18: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder
        21: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        24: astore_2
        25: new           #3                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
        28: dup
        29: invokespecial #4                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
        32: ldc           #5                  // String This is
        34: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder
        37: invokestatic  #7                  // Method getName:()Ljava/lang/String;
        40: invokevirtual #6                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder
        43: invokevirtual #8                  // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
        46: astore_3
        47: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        50: aload_1
        51: aload_2
        52: if_acmpne     59
        55: iconst_1
        56: goto          60
        59: iconst_0
        60: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
        63: getstatic     #9                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
        66: aload_3
        67: aload_2
        68: if_acmpne     75
        71: iconst_1
        72: goto          76
        75: iconst_0
        76: invokevirtual #10                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
        79: return
...
```

Based on this, I would say that s1 is interned whereas s2 and s3 are computed (using `StringBuilder`) at runtime.

Comment: Oh, that's some method to do this. Thanks for this tip, though I am yet to learn how to read Bytecode.

Comment: You do not need to understand all of the bytecode - the "// String" in the remarks shows the values used from the class file's constant pool.

Answer (score 1):

As **Conspect of String is immutable in java**.
Above result are true.
Whenever we append something in one string by concating creates a new reference in the String intern pool.

So if compare all above 3 Strings using **equals** methods its return True but false if compare using **==** operator.

Comment: Note that if you concatenate string literals, this is not the case. The expression is evaluated at compile-time and only the result is stored. So `"a" + "b"` results in only the string `"ab"` being created (and interned). Of course your statement is true for stuff that happens at runtime, such as `"a" + foo()`.

Comment: Yes, in any way new String created by appending another  String literal as you mentioned new String must be created in the intern pool.